# How to split a list into sublists using flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, split, sublist

I'm new with flutter.
I have data in txt file I retrieve it, then, I convert it into list and finally I split this list into sublists. Every sublist contains 19 values.
It's okey for this part. But now, the problem is that in the end of file we could have less than 19 values. So my question is how to add this values to another sublist also.
Actually, those sublists contains hexadecimals values, I was thinking about filling the last sublist with zeros until we have 19 values.But, I don't know how to do this.
Or, if you have any other solution to fix this issue?
this is my code:

```
  static Future<List> localPath() async {
    File textasset = File('/storage/emulated/0/RPSApp/assets/bluetooth.txt');
    final text = await textasset.readAsString();
    final bytes =
        text.split(',').map((s) => s.trim()).map((s) => int.parse(s)).toList();

    final chunks = [];
    //final list4 = [];
    int chunkSize = 19;

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i += chunkSize) {
      chunks.add(bytes.sublist(
          i, i + chunkSize > bytes.length ? bytes.length : i + chunkSize));
    }

    return chunks;
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; // add to your pubspec
final newList = originalList.slices(19).toList();
```

Done.  Read [the documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/slices.html) for details.

Edit: After reading your comment, I came up with this:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final random = Random();
  const chunkSize = 7;
  final source = List.generate(100, (index) => random.nextInt(100) + 1);

  List<int> padTo(List<int> input, int count) {
    return [...input, ...List.filled(count - input.length, 0)];
  }

  List<int> padToChunksize(List<int> input) => padTo(input, chunkSize);

  final items = source.slices(chunkSize).map(padToChunksize).toList();
  print(items);
}
```

which demonstrates how to pad each short list with more 0's.

Comment: this what will do ? I'm already splitting my list into sublists of 19 values

Comment: So this function will make groups of 19, and the last group might be less.  I had believed that was your question.  If you also want to pad any list shorter than 19 elements with 0's, that's just a bit more programming.

Comment: yes this  is the issue that I want to resolve it but I couldn't find a way to code this

Comment: See my edit. Should solve the padding problem.